# How to programmatically add suffix to the catalog title in Magento 2.2?

Tags: magento2, category, catalog, seo, page-title

I need to add the suffix to the catalog page title programmatically for SEO.

Currently in **view source code** i am getting catalog category page title like

```
<h1 class="page-title" id="page-title-heading" aria-labelledby="page-title-heading toolbar-amount">
    <span class="base" data-ui-id="page-title-wrapper" >Mobile</span>    
</h1>
```

**Mobile** - is the currently catalog category page title.
But i need to add suffix to the tile for catalog category pages.

For example:

```
<h1 class="page-title" id="page-title-heading" aria-labelledby="page-title-heading toolbar-amount">
    <span class="base" data-ui-id="page-title-wrapper" >Mobile Online </span>  
</h1>  

<h1 class="page-title" id="page-title-heading" aria-labelledby="page-title-heading toolbar-amount">
    <span class="base" data-ui-id="page-title-wrapper" >Computer Online </span>    
</h1>
```

So i need to add suffix Online for all category pages.
How can i achieve this?

Comment: suffix will be same for all categories ?

Comment: @Pawan yes, the suffix will be same for all categories.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pull down `magento2/app/code/Magento/Theme/view/adminhtml/templates/title.phtml` and set a different title template via catalog category view assuming you want to do this for only the catalog template... if you want to do it for everything (pages, products, modules etc) just pull down the file to your theme and do whatever changes you'd like.

Answer (score -1):

**Use jQuery function `append()`:**

For example:-

```
$("span.base").append(" Online");
```